# How to use ng-repeat in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

Do you have an idea ?

I tried to make an Array of arrays with `ng-repeat` like this :

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WRtqV/908/)

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = 
        [
         {'adam1': [{id:10, content:test1}, {id:11, content:test2},          
                    {id:12, content:test3}]}, 
         {'adam2': [{id:20, content:test4}, {id:21, content:test5},          
                    {id:30, content:test6}]}, 
         {'adam1': [{id:10, content:xxx}]}
         ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{key}}: {{value.content}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that (**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRtqV/910/)**):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        <li ng-repeat="obj in value">{{obj.content}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That said you might want to rearrange the structure so as to avoid nested `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of assigning variables works fine, but probably not as you're expecting: [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRtqV/909/)

The `content` item will not be available, as `value` is each object within the main array; you'll need to cycle through their properties (i.e. the `adamX` keys) to get the nested arrays.